# How can I read a key pressing only first time in LibGdx?

Tags: java

I am working on a amateur project and I have a problem. If you help, I'll be happy.
I am using `LibGdx` and in my program I must read something on keyboard in render function. When I used `isKeyPressed` like this:

```
if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.NUM_1)){
    x = 1;
try{
             Thread.sleep(500);
             }catch(InterruptedException e){}
    }
if(x == 1){
if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.NUM_1)){
...
    }
 }
```

If I press`NUM_1` and release it, part of ... is working. How can I prevent it. It is my first time with `LibGdx` and I couldn't find any way.

Comment: ***part of ... is working.*** ... can you explain a little bit more??

Comment: When I press NUM_1,only x must be 1, part  ... mustn't work and when I press NUM_1 retry ... must work.